# How to list all files in D:\ with the filepath.WalkDir

Tags: go

I want to list all txt files in D:\

```
func main() {
    var files []string

    filepath.WalkDir("D:\\", func(path string, entry fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        ok := strings.HasSuffix(path, ".txt")
        if ok {

            files = append(files, path)
        }

        return nil
    })
    for _, v := range files {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

but it doesn't list them in all directories.

Result:

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1494130436-1676888839-3129388282-1001\$I1KMI26.txt
D:\GoLand 2022.2.3\build.txt
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. Can you share with us your directory structure? what folders or files are ignored?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020059/filepath-walk-only-files-dot-files.
Are you getting an error on some files? may be access denied?

Comment: if i remove "strings.HasSuffix(path, ".txt")", it can list all files in all dirctories, but if i want to specify the txt file uh.. it's unsatisfactory

Comment: i resolve the problem
"if err != nil { return err}"　is the troble maker

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```golang
// ListFiles is delegated to find the files from the given directory, recursively for each dir
func ListFiles(path string) ([]string, error) {
    var fileList []string
    // Read all the file recursively
    if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return nil, err
    }
    err := filepath.Walk(path, func(file string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if IsFile(file) {
            fileList = append(fileList, file)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return fileList, nil
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/blob/a8a2dce47f1e7187aa96580f75a9c8786797b2e5/files/fileutils.go#L185